# ReactJS dangerouslySetInnerHTML removes data attributes

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, dom

When I add `data-test` attribute to `a` anchor tag in html string and then insert it with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` the `data` attributes are being stripped out. How can I disable it? I need that attributes for E2E testing. Or maybe there is an alternative way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected, check that you've proper closing tags.

```js
const App = () => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {
 { __html: '<a data-test="this-is-a-test" href="/bla">test</a>'}
} />
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I thought this way is not working and then I noticed that I was doing changes in one environment and checking in a different place